# Embedding matplotlib chart using FigureCanvasTkAgg - set xticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am creating a GUI which includes a variety of embedded charts. I am using **matplotlib** and **FigureCanvasTkAgg** with **tkinter** to do so and everything is working fine apart from the x axis labels. I can easily set the labels using **plt.xticks** when creating a matplotlib chart that appears in a new window but not when using **FigureCanvasTkAgg**.

I have not included my full code as it is far too long, but I have included all the code I think is relevant (pyplot is used elsewhere but should not be relevant to my problem). The **chart.set_xticks** here does not actually do anything: instead of showing the labels in the list titled **objects**, it shows 0 then goes up in integers with every other data point actually labelled as per the image below. I have tried various different things using **chart.set_xticks**, but can only remove all labels using **chart.set_xticks([])** or specify integers using **chart.set_xticks([0,1,2,3...])** which labels each data point but not with the labels I require.

Any ideas?

[image: Bar chart without correct x labels]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

objects = ["2x", "3x", "4x", "5x", "6x", "7x", "8x", "9x", "10x", "11x", "12x", "Year 2", "Year 3", "Year 4"]    
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))

fig = Figure(figsize=(font * 8, font * 5))

chart = fig.add_subplot(111)
chart.set_ylim(ymin=0, ymax=32)
chart.bar(y_pos, plotList, color=colours, alpha=0.5, label="Table")
chart.bar(y_pos, inversePlotList, color=colours, label="Inverse")
chart.set_xticks(y_pos, objects)
chart.set_ylabel("Average score")
chart.legend()

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=userTablesFrame)
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
canvas.draw()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation of `plt.xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html):

> Calling this function with arguments is the pyplot equivalent of calling set_xticks and set_xticklabels on the current axes.

So to get the same behavior you should use both `set_xticks` and `set_xticklabels`:

```
chart.set_xticks(y_pos)
chart.set_xticklabels(objects)
```